# How to add a Many to Many association in NestJs Sequlize and Mysql2

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js, nestjs, many-to-many

Its simple. I have blogs model, events model and a tags model. I want to link the blog with tags as many to many relation. I was able to set up the 3 tables in database plus blogtag and eventtag mapping tables . But I can not find a way to insert tags to blogs( I can create blogs but can not add an entry to blogtag table). Here is the code. I can create blogs but no luck in attaching them with their tags

```
   import {
  Table,
  Column,
  Model,
  DataType,
  CreatedAt,
  UpdatedAt,
  DeletedAt,
  ForeignKey,
  BelongsTo,
  BelongsToMany
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import { User } from '../../users/entities/user.entity';
import  {BlogTag, Tag} from '../../tags/entities/tag.entity'

@Table
export class Blog extends Model<Blog> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  })
  public id: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  title: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  blogData: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.BIGINT,
    allowNull: false,
  })
  userId: number;

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
  user: User;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  })
  imageUrl: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: false,
  })
  checked: boolean;

  @CreatedAt public createdAt: Date;

  @UpdatedAt public updatedAt: Date;

  @DeletedAt public deletedAt: Date;

  @BelongsToMany( ()=> Tag, ()=> BlogTag)
  tags: Tag[]
}
```

this is blogs.ts

```
import {
    Table,
    Column,
    Model,
    DataType,
    CreatedAt,
    UpdatedAt,
    DeletedAt,
    ForeignKey,
    BelongsTo,
    BelongsToMany,
  } from 'sequelize-typescript';
  import { User } from '../../users/entities/user.entity';
  import { Event } from 'src/events/entities/event.entity';
  import { Blog } from 'src/blogs/entities/blog.entity';
  
  @Table
  export class Tag extends Model<Tag> {
    @Column({
      type: DataType.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    })
    public id: number;
  
    @Column({
      type: DataType.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    })
    name: string;

    @BelongsToMany( ()=> Blog, ()=> BlogTag)
    blogs: Blog[]
  
    @BelongsToMany( ()=> Event, ()=> EventTag)
    events: Event[]
  }
  
  @Table
  export class BlogTag extends Model<BlogTag>{
    @ForeignKey(() => Blog)
    @Column({
      type: DataType.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
    })
    blogId: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Tag)
    @Column({
      type: DataType.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
    })
    tagId: number;
}
```

this is tags  and this is my dto for blogs

```
export class CreateBlogDto {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly checked: boolean;
  readonly blogData: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  readonly userId: number;
  tags: number[];
}
```

here is my service

```
  async createBlog(createBlogDto: CreateBlogDto, blog_image) {
createBlogDto.imageUrl = blog_image.path;
// const tags = await this.tagService.getTagsByIds(createBlogDto.tags)
console.log(createBlogDto)
// console.log(tags)
// createBlogDto.tags = tags
return await this.blogRepository.create<Blog>(createBlogDto);
```

}
here is my controller.

```
      @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Post()
  create(
    @Body() createBlogDto: CreateBlogDto,
    @U[![**enter image description here**][1]][1]ploadedFile()
    blog_image: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    return this.blogsService.createBlog(createBlogDto, blog_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this: [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/) after you define your models to assign tags to a blog

you have to inject your BlogTag model into your service and call the create method on the BlogTag model with the created blog id and each if of provided tags in the createBlogDto

```
export class BlogService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(BlogTag) private blogTagModel: typeof BlogTag,
              @InjectModel(Blog) private blogModel: typeof Blog) {
  }
  async createBlog(createBlogDto: CreateBlogDto): Promise<Blog> {
    const blog = await this.blogModel.create(createBlogDto);
    const blogTags = await this.blogTagModel.findAll({
      where: {
        id: {[Op.in] : createBlogDto.tags}
      },
    });
    if (createBlogDto.tags && createBlogDto.tags.length) {
      await this.assignTagsToBlog(blog.id, createBlogDto.tags);
    }
    return blog.save();
  }

  async assignTagsToBlog(blogId: number, tags: number[]): Promise<Blog> {
    const blog = await this.blogModel.findByPk(blogId);
    for (const tag of tags) {
      await  this.blogTagModel.create({
        blogId: blogId,
        tagId: tag
      })
    }
    return blog;
  }
}
```

`assignTagsToBlog` is a function that will be used to add and assign tags to the a blog that equal to the same id as pararmter

Comment: where can i import Op.in?

Comment: Op can be imported form sequalize package it self import {Op} from 'sequalize'